# Aventail VPN connection doesn't work

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, vpn, dns, parallels

I installed the Aventail VPN client on both the Mac and a Windows 7 machine, both on my home network.

When I try to connect one or the other (I make sure one is disconnected before connecting through the other machine), I get a connection and view the correct certificate - accept it and Aventail tells me that I am connected.

However, accessing any page inside my company's network is only possible on Windows.
On the Mac I get this page:

[image]

It looks like my ISP doesn't know how to redirect me?  Maybe something about my DNS being set incorrectly on the Mac?

Our helpdesk has been completely useless.

Comment: hi Warlax-
Did you ever make any headway with this?
I am trying to use Aventail VPN right now, and running into lots of trouble- I've been told I can only use it on Windows, and not been connecting properly. So am trying to connect with Aventail Mac software, but also having trouble (since just like you experienced, the company's network seems to want windows.)
Thoughts? I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I have used aventail on my network in my lab and have found out that you need to run your web browser as root/superuser, and have the latest version of java installed. once this is done it worked for me